# UPS and surge protector sharing an outlet

Tags: security

I hope this is not a stupid question.
Would it be safe to plug in a UPS and surge protector power strip into the same outlet?

My PC and monitor is hooked up to the UPS while TV + Router/Modem on the surge protector power bar.

I'm worried about overloads or anything happening while all these devices are running at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be safe to plug in a UPS and surge protector power strip into the same outlet?

It is perfectly safe.  This would effectively happen if you plugged the surge protector into the UPS.  Your outlet also has built-in protection it seems.

> I'm worried about overloads or anything happening while all these devices are running at the same time

Any overloads would be at the circuit breaker. **At the worst, you will trip a breaker, for the circuit in question.**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

One more thing, because in my old place (I recently moved) one of the outlets are slightly melted? or burnt, it's got this brownish color on it. I can't remember when or why but all I know is that one time I smelt burning plastic and traced it back to that outlet. I did have some guest stay with me a few days and they used that outlet, but I cannot figure out what cause that, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: That seems unrelated to the question you have asked.  If you are concern consult an electrician.  The outlet in the body of your question does not have that problem, provided, the screenshot is an accurate representation of the outlet.  **If it is not accurate, then my answer does not apply, since the outlet is damaged.**

Comment: One minor note: GFCI's sometimes trip due to current surges, even when there is no issue. This *could* leave the UPS running on batteries. Not a safety issue, but you should be aware that the circuit could be opened even though the over-current circuit breaker in the main panel does not trip.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Appreciate the extra bit of information.

Comment: Good point by DrMoishe Pippik.  For that reason, it's never a good idea to plug a UPS into any outlet protected by a GFCI (one GFCI outlet often protects other "downstream" outlets, like in a kitchen).  The GFCI breaker can pop when you're not there, or you may not even be aware of it if you are there.  So the UPS battery can run down.  Unless you have software to gracefully power down your computer when the UPS battery reaches a certain level, the situation is the same as having no UPS at all.